# "Use the LLVM optimizing compiler" causes my iOS location longitude to be strange

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, compilation, core-location

I'm using iOS location to get my current location.  In my Xamarin Studio Project options, if I go to iOS Build and enable "Use the LLVM optimizing compiler".  My iOS location longitude becomes a strange value.

What my lat long SHOULD be and is

```
"lat": 37.22916715781878, 
"long": -121.98161104705369,
```

What my lat long is after I enable "Use the LLVM optimizing compiler".

```
"lat": 37.22915781199674, 
"long": 2.1498794687e-314,
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: A `CLLocationDegrees` type a native Double, are you using 64-bit floats, doing any casts (explicit or implicit) on the return values from CLLocationManager's `getLocation`?...

Comment: I believe that may be the case, but i'm going to investigate to see exactly where.